# Type 'Any' has no subscript members while getting response from web service while using web socket

Tags: ios, json, swift3, websocket

I have tried Dictionary in place of Any but I have not found the required value
I want to print only "msg" value from text value from the following code

```
webSocket.event.message = { message in
            if let text = message as? Any {
                print("recv: \(text)")//recv: {"status":"200","msg":"successful"}
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
                var time = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
                self.messagesReceived["messageReceived"] = text["msg"]
                self.messagesReceived["time"] = time
                self.messagesDetails["received"] = self.messagesReceived

            }
        }
```

Comment: is message by itself a `Dictonoary` or some kind of encoded data, like json?

Comment: it is  json data, I am getting it from webService u can see I am implementing WebSocket.event.message with closure

Comment: Please learn to understand what the error message means. Collection types can be subscripted by index (array), or key (dictionary). `Any`can be anything, a string, a number, a date, a collection type etc., the static type is unspecified. So if you want to subscript the object by key (`text["msg"]`) you have to make sure (and inform the compiler) that the subscripted object is a dictionary. An optional binding to `Any` is nonsensical anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting string message from the server.

```
webSocket.event.message = { message in
    if let text = message as? String, let responseData = let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            let responseDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as? [String: Any]
            //Your code
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you , its working ! Can you please suggest me a solution without using an extra function( convertToDictionary) in my code  if its possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
    webSocket.event.message = { message in
        if let data = (message as! String).data(using: .utf8) {
            do {
                let text = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
                let time = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
                self.messagesReceived["messageReceived"] = text!["msg"] as? String
                self.messagesReceived["time"] = time
                self.messagesDetails["received"] = self.messagesReceived
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    messagesDisplay.append(messagesDetails)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```